# Magento 1: guide to pixel tracking module development

Tags: module, checkout, extensions, magento-1

I was wondering if someone could write a generic guide to **develop a pixel tracking module.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **generic guide you can write to develop a pixel tracking module**. As it is generic you will have to adapt that code (specially the template code) to match your requirements:

`app/etc/modules/DigitalPianism_PixelTracking.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DigitalPianism_PixelTracking>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
            </depends>
        </DigitalPianism_PixelTracking>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/DigitalPianism/PixelTracking/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    <modules>
        <DigitalPianism_PixelTracking>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </DigitalPianism_PixelTracking>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <pixeltracking module="DigitalPianism_PixelTracking">
                    <file>digitalpianism/pixeltracking.xml</file>
                </pixeltracking>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <pixeltracking>
                <class>DigitalPianism_PixelTracking_Block</class>
            </pixeltracking>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <pixeltracking>
                <class>DigitalPianism_PixelTracking_Helper</class>
            </pixeltracking>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

(Optional) `app/code/local/DigitalPianism/PixelTracking/etc/system.xml`

Depending on your requirements **you may want to create a system configuration fields file in order to make your tracking configurable (for example you can add tracking URL, API key, a switch to enable/disable the tracking)**

(Optional) `app/code/local/DigitalPianism/PixelTracking/etc/adminhtml.xml`

If you add a new configuration section **you will need this file for the ACL**.

`app/code/local/DigitalPianism/PixelTracking/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

class DigitalPianism_PixelTracking_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract 
{
}
```

NB: **if you have added system configuration fields you can create the corresponding utility methods here to be able to retrieve the value via the helper.**

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/digitalpianism/pixeltracking.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="pixeltracking/tracker" name="pixeltracking" template="digitalpianism/pixeltracking/tracker.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

Now it's time to create your block class. **It will contain all the methods necessary for your tracking**, the example below is a generic example but you can add whatever methods you need in your template:

```
<?php

class DigitalPianism_PixelTracking_Block_Tracker extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    protected $_lastOrderId;
    protected $_lastOrder;
    protected $_store;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
        $this->_lastOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->_lastOrderId);
        $this->_store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    }

    public function getLastOrder()
    {
         return $this->_lastOrder;
    }

    public function getLastOrderId()
    {
         return $this->_lastOrderId;
    }

    public function getOrderItems()
    {
         return $this->_lastOrder->getAllItems();
    }

    public function getCurrencyCode()
    {
         return $this->_store->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }
}
```

Finally you can create your template file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/digitalpianism/pixeltracking/tracker.phtml`

```
<?php

$lastOrderId = $this->getLastOrderId();
$lastOrder = $this->getLastOrder();
$orderItems = $this->getOrderItems();
$currency = $this->getCurrencyCode();

// Display your pixel tracker here
```

**This template is probably the most custom part and you will have to add the specific code of your tracker in replacement of the comment.**